# How can I deploy Flask Heroku App crashed

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy flask app, then connect with android studio by heroku. I am getting error "App crashed". I've searched for some answers, but didn't find right one

Procfile:
`web: python3 main.py -p $PORT`

Error:

```
2022-04-29T21:14:37.415074+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" hos
t=inaieventapp.herokuapp.com request_id=df271a69-dffe-495d-80e0-605baa25eba5 fwd="193.34.225.47" dyno= connec
t= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-04-29T21:14:38.852245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favic
on.ico" host=inaieventapp.herokuapp.com request_id=61261f12-96e3-46e5-a9f8-26a6ad9a4dd5 fwd="193.34.225.47" d
yno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

part of main.py:

```
load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.config["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongodb+srv://kawwai:*******@kawwai.mmmn3.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
app.config["MONGO_DBNAME"] = 'kawwai'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

user_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
user_put_args.add_argument('name', type=str)
user_put_args.add_argument('email', type=str)
user_put_args.add_argument('studentId', type=str)
user_put_args.add_argument('id', type=str)

event_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
event_put_args.add_argument('title', type=str)
event_put_args.add_argument('date', type=str)
event_put_args.add_argument('startTime', type=str)
event_put_args.add_argument('endTime', type=str)
event_put_args.add_argument('location', type=str)
event_put_args.add_argument('description', type=str)
```